# Connect to different servers offering the same web service with WSDL

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl

I'm entirely new to web services and all I've been able to do is a Hello World

My situation is the following, I have some servers which provide a WSDL file, all the servers provide the same file and methods, they just have different IPs/ports. In addition each server contains its own set of users.

I know how to communicate to work with one WSDL at a time, but I need 2 things:

- Being able to add web services dynamically (connect/disconnect to other servers)
- Being able to perform methods on the right server as the right user (you cant make a request if your user does not exist on the server you are asking to)

I have no idea of where to start, can someone point me in a direction to solve those 2 problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specific in terms of libraries you use.

For example if you use CXF (Jax-WS in general) you can do the following:

```
// change endpoint URL
((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "new url");
// new username. password will be provided by WS callback
((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, "username");
```

If you're using Spring for the infrastructure you can autowire all proxies with one statement:

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, ServiceInterface> interfaces;
```

If you want to *add web services dynamically* you have to decide whether this *dynamically* means *at any time* or *at application startup* - this however has nothing to do with web services - it's general programming model of autodiscovery (you can use database, one single remote source of available services, etc.)